# BindingPaths do not seem to be honored when loading referenced Assemblies from within a Visual Studio Extension with custom dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I created an Visual Studio 2013 extension that uses referenced assemblies. These assemblies are installed by the vsix to a subfolder of the package folder. 
I also added this subfolder with the `ProvideBindingPath` attribute to the `.pkgdef` file. The registry (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0_config\BindingPaths\{PACKAGEGUID}`) is updated with the correct path on installation of the vsix.

So the `MyExtension.pkgdef` looks like that:

```
...
[$RootKey$\InstalledProducts\MyPackage]
@="#110"
"Package"="{f9c9068e-d551-49b1-b3c5-ffaff2ad6398}"
"PID"="3.0.0.5"
"ProductDetails"="#112"
"LogoID"="#400"
[$RootKey$\BindingPaths\{F9C9068E-D551-49B1-B3C5-FFAFF2AD6398}]
"$PackageFolder$\\LibsV3"=""
[$RootKey$\BindingPaths\{F9C9068E-D551-49B1-B3C5-FFAFF2AD6398}]
"$PackageFolder$"=""
...
```

This is what `extension.vsixmanifest` looks like

```
<PackageManifest>
 <Metadata>
    <Identity Id="F9C9068E-D551-49B1-B3C5-FFAFF2AD6398" Version="3.0.0.5" Language="en-US" Publisher="kmavize" />
     ...
  <Assets>
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.VsPackage" Path="MyExtension.pkgdef" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" Path="MyEditor3.dll" AssemblyName="MyEditor3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5555555555555555" />
    <Asset Type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Assembly" Path="LibsV3\MyRefAssembly.dll" AssemblyName="MyRefAssembly, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5555555555555555" />
    ...
  </Assets>
</PackageManifest>
```

When my custom editor loads I get an exception that the referenced assemblies (the ones in LibsV3 folder) can not be found.

I did put the these referenced assemblies in the LibsV3 subfolder so that my T4 templates, that are also part of my extension, are able to distinguish between the current version (V3) assemblies and older version assemblies with the same name used in a different extension (that my be installed at the same time).

Maybe there is another way to solve my initial problem with the T4 Templates so I don't run in the assembly not found exception...

Comment: It might be helpful to share the full .pkgdef contents to pastebin/gist/something else.

Comment: I edited the question and added some "code" and further explanation.

Comment: Something to try, although I don't think it'll matter -- you don't need your additional binding redirect to have the same GUID as your package. The GUID there is just arbitrary to prevent collisions. It's possible that since your pkgdef has two redirects under the same GUID something is getting confused.

Comment: Perfect that worked... I didn't know that the actual GUID is just arbitrary. There is also a couple of other registry keys under `BindingPaths` that have multiple entries. Anyway it works now... Thank you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason suggested I just added the second path under a new registry key and it works.

So my `pkgdef` now looks like that:

```
...
[$RootKey$\InstalledProducts\MyPackage]
@="#110"
"Package"="{f9c9068e-d551-49b1-b3c5-ffaff2ad6398}"
"PID"="3.0.0.5"
"ProductDetails"="#112"
"LogoID"="#400"
[$RootKey$\BindingPaths\{16766769-9969-4A46-A76B-76698F6374F2}]
"$PackageFolder$\\LibsV3"=""
[$RootKey$\BindingPaths\{F9C9068E-D551-49B1-B3C5-FFAFF2AD6398}]
"$PackageFolder$"=""
...
```